# How to programmatically add attribute option values in data upgrade script?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade-script

I want to programmatically add new product option values in a data upgade script of my module. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add bellow code in your upgrade script file

```
<?php   
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

if ($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput()=='select') {
    $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
    $option['value']        =  array('Red','Black', 'Yellow');
    $installer->addAttributeOption($option);
}

//OR
/*
if($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput()=='select') {
    $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
    $option['value']['r'][0] = 'Red';
    $option['value']['b'][1] = 'Black';
    $option['value']['y'][2] = 'Yellow';
    $installer->addAttributeOption($option);
}*/

$installer->endSetup();
```

**Check duplicate option value code:**

```
<?php   
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

 if($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput()=='select') {
    $newOptions =  array('Red','Black', 'Yellow');
    $exitOptions =  array();
    $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                        ->setAttribute($attribute)
                        ->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if (in_array($option['label'], $newOptions)) {
            array_push($exitOptions, $option['label']);
        }else {

        }
    }
    $insertOptions = array_diff($newOptions, $exitOptions);
    if(!empty($insertOptions)) {
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
        $option['value']        =  $insertOptions;  
        $installer->addAttributeOption($option);
    }            
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: What is the meaning of indexes `'r'`, `'b'`, `'y'` in `$option['value']['r'][0] = 'Red';`?

Comment: That creates a broken drop-down option here, on Magento CE 1.9. Table `eav_attribute_option` gets one new row, but without a corresponding row in `eav_attribute_option_value`. Must be something with the `$option` array structure.

Comment: Please can you help me to check the attribute value if that value is already available. So duplicate value not insert in attribute

Comment: @Purushotam Sharma : Updates ans pls check and let me know it is working or not bec i am not tested code.

Comment: hello @Abdul!  its not adding option while running this script

Comment: @ SagarPPanchal  have u created attribute type drop-down(select)?

Comment: yes @Abdul, simply adding another attributes but not adding

Comment: Pls check now. I have updated ans

Comment: yes, checked this as well, https://codeshare.io/06032018, but new values are not adding

Comment: Let me check you code

Comment: used this  $option['value']        =  $insertOptions;

Comment: @Abdul you mean, replace values to value ?

Comment: Yes, You are right. Someone  edit my original code

Comment: no change @Abdul

Comment: well its displaying differ array but not saving in option values

Comment: can share you magento ver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74101/discussion-between-sagarppanchal-and-abdul).

Comment: perfect answer !!! +1 :)

Answer (score 12):

try this,

for single value:-

```
$arg_attribute = 'color';
$arg_value = 'red';

$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
$attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();

$option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
$option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

for multiple values:-

```
$arg_attribute = 'color';
$key_data = array('red','black','orange');
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
foreach($key_data as $key_value)
{   
    $option = array();
    $arg_value = trim($key_value);
    $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();
    $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
    $option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;
    $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
}
```

'any_option_name' would be a color_name (ex: red)
arg_value would be it's integer optionId afaik.

The thing that would also need to be acquired first, is what the next unused optionId is. To be used for this new attribute option.

Answer (score 6):

For example, you want to add `Men` value to `gender` option.

First you have to create your upgrade script in module directory, e.g. `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/data/mymodule_setup/data-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php`.

Then fill it with code like this:

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

$genderAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'gender'); // 'gender' is your attribute code

$this->addAttributeOption([
    'attribute_id' => $genderAttribute->getId(),
    'value' => [[0 => 'Men', 1 => 'Men', 10 => 'Men']] // array indexes are store IDs
]);

$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code add attributes options programmatically magento 1.

Please refer for detailed explanation how to read from CSV and compare with existing attribute options
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/add-attribute-options-magento-scripts/

```
function createAttribute( $options , $attributeCode) {
$option = array('attribute_id' => 
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode(
     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
     $attributeCode
    )
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {

    $option['value']['option'.$i][0] = $options[ $i ]; // Store View
    $option['value']['option'.$i][1] = $options[ $i ]; // Default store view
    $option['order']['option'.$i] = $i; // Sort Order
    echo 'Insert new option : '.$options[ $i ].PHP_EOL;

}

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on Magento 1 (OpenMage LTS 19.4.11)

This code works correctly:

```
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$option = [];
$option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
$option['value'] = [
    'option_1' => ['value 1'],
    'option_2' => ['value 2'],
    'option_3' => ['value 3'],
];
$installer->addAttributeOption($option);
```

You can use it **not only** on the install script